# How to programmatically pass value to stored procedure in Devexpress Reports

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I want to pass parameter value from my form to DevExpress Report which shows data from the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SelectionOrder
    (@Id int)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

I want to pass parameter `@Id` value from my form in Devexpress Report.

I'm using the following code - but it is not working:

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1(); 
report.Parameters["Id"].Value = 138;
report.ShowPreview();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using the `SqlDataSource` component.

- add the `SqlDataSource` via wizard
- configure it to use a stored procedure
- in the wizard page "configure query parameters" expand the parameter value dropdown and select the "expression" where you can add the report parameter

For more information can read the topic:

[Bind a report to a stored procedure](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10555/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/provide-data-to-reports/bind-a-report-to-a-data-source/sql-database/bind-a-report-to-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add Parameters to report first.

[image]

2. Then select expression in report procedure and assign your parameter.

[image]

3. The Report will automatically ask parameters before execution.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1(); 
report.Parameters["Id"].Value = 138;

 ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
 printTool.AutoShowParametersPanel = false;
 printTool.ShowPreview();
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?